# How to add an entry to fstab?

Tags: disk, fstab

I unmounted a disk (`/dev/vdc1`) on my server machine (it doesn't have a graphical environment) and then formatted it as an xfs file system. I forgot to mount it again and also didn't add the respective line to my `fstab` file.

Now, after rebooting the server, I want to mount this partition, but I can't access it. I get this error:

```
mount: can't find dev/vdc1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
```

So how should I edit my `fstab` file so that the system recognizes the partition again? The partition was mounted on `/Data`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

So here we create an `fstab` entry for the partition.

1. You need to create the folder for the partition and get the device id. Open a terminal. The folder can be created via:

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/Data
   ```

   In addition, I would make the user the owner and give him the right to read/write:

   ```
   sudo chown [user]:[group] /media/Data
   sudo chmod +rw /media/Data
   ```
2. Now the `fstab` entry.

   - Install `libblkid1` to see device specific information:

     ```
     sudo apt-get install libblkid1
     ```
   - Enter `sudo blkid` and look for the stick. The output could be:

     ```
     /dev/sda2: UUID="32a4b76f-246e-486e-8495-31b8a781fb4c" TYPE="swap" 
     /dev/sda1: UUID="31f39d50-16fa-4248-b396-0cba7cd6eff2" TYPE="ext4"
     ```
   - Then we create the `fstab` entry:

     ```
     sudo nano /etc/fstab
     ```

     and append the line:

     ```
     UUID=31f39d50-16fa-4248-b396-0cba7cd6eff2     /media/Data   auto    rw,user,auto    0    0
     ```

     (and afterwards give a empty new line to avoid warnings).

To mount the partition, open a terminal and run:

```
mount /media/Data
```

Because of the entry `auto` it should be mounted automatically on next boot.

Before the next boot, don't forget to verify the entries! On any error in the `fstab` file, the system will not start and you will need to recover it, by reverting the changes. You can verify the entries with:

```
sudo findmnt --verify
```

Answer (score 7):

First you need to find out UUID of your disk by following  command

```
sudo blkid
```

Note your disk UUID.

Now open fstab file with gedit

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Replace your old disk UUID with your noted UUID.
Save file and reboot your system. You will be able to mount disk.

Comment: Thank you for the replay, i tried "sudo blkid" i got only UUID for : /dev/vda1 and /dev/vda2, is like there is no /dev/vdc1 disk (on the same time, there is this partition, cause i attached a storage disk to my server mounted on /Data and worked on it, before i do the unmount), sorry for the late replay

Comment: Not yet, but i'm gonna do it, cause i think my problem has no relation with linux, it's the storage disk's catalogue

Comment: Can you tell us more about your hardware setup? Doesn't seem to be an standard HDD

Answer (score 3):

While Manuel seems to have answered the asked question quite fully, the question you seem to have meant to ask was:

> *"After I unmounted a disk `/dev/vdc1` from `/Data` and formatted it to XFS, I can't remount it.  How do I remount it at `/Data`?"*

You seem to be misunderstanding (reasonably) the error message help text that results, which is what's caused confusion about your question.

You unmounted the device, `/dev/vdc1`, from `/Data`, formatted the device to XFS, then tried to remount it and it's saying there's no such device.  Since you didn't give details on the exact command(s) you ran to "format the device to XFS", I'm going to assume what you did was:

```
sudo mkfs.xfs -f /dev/vdc1
```

If you forgot the `-f`, or didn't answer `yes` to a prompt to overwrite the existing file system, the `mkfs` command failed.

After doing this, you should just be able to run the command

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/vdc1 /Data
```

Looking at the error that was generated, it appears you entered `dev/vdc1`, rather than `/dev/vdc1`, and/or reversed the arguments to the mount command.

If it's still giving you an error for some reason, confirm that `/dev/vdc1` actually exists.  You can check `/var/log/syslog` or run `dmesg` to see what the system did after you created the new file system to determine if it decided to change the device associated with the partition for some reason, or what explicit error occurred when you ran the mount command that failed.