# Mount external devices into home with specialised folder icons

Tags: 13.10, mountpoint

I wish to mount separate 3TB drives as /home/markrich/Pictures, /home/markrich/Music and /home/markrich/Videos.

Mounting the drives isn't a problem for me, however is Ubuntu clever enough to assign the current default folder icons to these new mounted drives with the music symbol, Polaroids and film strips upon them or will they end up generic with a disc icon upon them?

If the later, how can I amend?

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible ways is using [Ubuntu tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak).

- Open ubuntu tweak and go to **Admins >
  User folder** and then click on the folder you want to change. Click on "Change" and browse to the folder which you want to mount on.

[image: ubuntu tweak -admin and user folder]

[image: change folder mount]

- You should mount these drives on boot for nautilus to detect those folders everytime you reboot. For this, add those partitions to `/etc/fstab`.

To know how to do this, see this question:

- [Add an entry to fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303497/adding-an-entry-to-fstab)

[image: voila you have it]