# how to copy file from external hard disk to Ubuntu on my PC

Tags: external-hdd

I am using Ubuntu mate on my PC. I want to copy video from my hard disk to my PC. When I connect, I will get notification but when I search I am not able to find my hard disk folder. Please help me.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate's default file manager (I suppose it's Caja) should display external drives in the left bar. Open the file manager and it should be there.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to open Terminal(Ctrl+Alt+T) and run command **fdisk -l** . You will then see lists of partitions on your system such as /dev/sda1-2-3-4. 
You need to identify by size or system information.

Once you recognized your drive your need to mount your drive to one of directory in your system. Below command to mount your drive:

## sudo mound /dev/sda*

Please add entry in FSTAB to make your mount point permanent. 
[Adding an entry to fstab](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303497/adding-an-entry-to-fstab)

Once you mount your drive to your system. You can copy your data.

I hope this will help. Cheers :)

Thanks: 
Gursharan Singh

Comment: after I run the command sudo fdisk -l, it is not showing my 1TB external hard disk. it is showing below details.

Comment: `Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *         2048 102762495 102760448   49G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       102764542 104855551   2091010 1021M  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       102764544 104855551   2091008 1021M 82 Linux swap / Solaris`