# Just installed Lubuntu and it doesn't show my disks (D:\, E:\ and ...). What can I do?

Tags: lubuntu

I've just installed Lubuntu 17.10 on my laptop and removed Windows 7. But I can't find my former hard disks (D:\, E:). When I tried Lubuntu without installing ( and deleting the previous os ) I could use my hard disks. But they have disappeared. What can I do?

Comment: Restore a backup? You picked the option to replace Windows. That removes all windows related partitions.

Comment: Can I install the previous partitions somehow on Lubuntu? I don't know much about partitioning @Rinzwind

Comment: I can't tell if you're saying that the partitions are gone, or that you just aren't sure how to mount them?

Answer (score 0):

As @Rinzwind pointed out in comments, you've overwritten your Windows partitions with Lubuntu -- unless you have a backup, all the information that was on the computer is gone.  If you have additional physical drives, however, they won't have been touched by the install; you merely need to add entries for them into `/etc/fstab` so they'll automount when Lubuntu starts.  There's documentation available on how to format an fstab entry, and you'll want/need something that will read the UUID from each volume (UUID is strongly preferred over volume label or device notation, as it doesn't change unless the volume is formatted).

Comment: Do you really mean all the data on the other disks like D:\ and E:\ are gone? Really? How can installing an os remove all the data on my disks. I've got a backup in the disk E:\ do you mean it's gone too?

Comment: If you chose "use the entire disk" when you installed Lubuntu, it did exactly what you told it -- erased everything on the physical disk and automatically created one or more partitions for itself.  If you chose "install alongside Windows", then all you need to do is get the UUIDs of those other volumes and add them to `/etc/fstab` as noted in my answer and the other one.

Comment: Sorry for asking too lot i'm very nervous, but I had three hard disks and only one of them (C:\) contained the windows files. I chose "use the entire disk". Do you mean that the D:\ and E:\ disks are also erased?

Comment: Were C:, D: and E: three real physical disks or were they partitions on one single physical disk?

Comment: "I chose 'use the entire disk'" -- that means anything on the physical disk that now contains Lubuntu was erased.  Information on other physical drives should be untouched, but those volumes won't automount until you manually add them to `/etc/fstab`.  If your C, D, and E partitions were all on the same hardware device, they're all gone.  If not, the ones that weren't on the "first" device (as seen by the Lubuntu install media) will be fine.

Comment: Three partitions of the same disk. Now I understand. My data is gone. thanks for replying me...

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that.  For future reference, this is why it's not a perfect plan to keep your backup on the same physical device as the data it's supposed to protect.  User errors aside, if the device fails, the backup is gone, too.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Install a utility such as `gparted` . It will scan your hard disk and you'll come to know if those partitions exist in the first place or not.

If they exist, select the partition you want , right click and select "Information" There you'll get the "UUID"

Now you'll need to add entries to fstab.. follow this guide [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/303497/adding-an-entry-to-fstab)