# Mount vmdk disk ubuntu?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, 15.10, vmdk

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 in VMware Workstation. 
HOST OS -WINDOWS 10

Now my hard disk  is full and i attached a new vmdk hard disk and rebooted the system but while trying to mount it using  `sudo /dev/sdb1 /data` it's giving following error

```
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb
```

How to properly mount hard vmdk disk?

Comment: What is you host OS, which supervisor do you run VMWare (question body) or VirtualBox (tag)? Did you partition and format the new drive after creation?

Comment: @Panther , i went  through them but they are not helping me

Comment: @Takkat , OS , windows 10  and i caanot partition as its not visible in my ubuntu , only i can see it  in  fdisk - l utility

Comment: What command did you run and what error message did you get?

Comment: @Karamzov you need to run gparted in the guest Ubuntu for patitioning.

Comment: @Takkat ,  paritioned using gparted and  tried to mount using  `sudo /dev/sdb /data` , its giving the same error

Comment: @Panther This question is not a duplicate. Karamzov asks how to use a new vmdk in an Ubuntu guest whereas the other question asks how to mount a vmdk in an Ubuntu host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vmdk disk for a virtual system is like a bare hardware disk for a native system. You can't mount bare disks, only filesystems. So you have to partition your vmdk disk and make filesystems on it (with gparted and mkfs).

Partitioning gives you a partition named /dev/sdb1.
Then you create a filesystem with for example `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1`. Now you can mount /dev/sdb1.

Comment: Partion done  and now i tried to mount using mount /dev/sdb /data but its giving an error

Comment: If you have done partitioning the first partition is named /dev/sdb1. You have to make a filesystem in your partition, for example `mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdb1`, then you can mount /dev/sdb1.

Comment: its done and mounted , i was thinking microsoft way and this made it difficult. now its mounted and is  accessable

Comment: Done............

Comment: i have one more question, is is posssible to attach the current partion to my existing partion that is merging sdb with sda

Comment: As the name 'partition' says, partitions are separate. If you want to use /dev/sdb1 for let's say your pictures, you could create a folder /home/<my user>/my_pictures, then `mount /dev/sdb1 /home/<my user>/my_pictures`. If you include your new filesystem in `/etc/fstab` it can be automatically mounted at boot time and you can use it like your primary device.

Comment: how to add this in /etc/fstab  ?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/303497/adding-an-entry-to-fstab